# div tag inside table

Tags: jquery, html

When i am clicking on `<input type="text" class="form-control" value="13:14">` not in table it working well.

[image]

But when i am clicking on `<input type="text" class="form-control" value="13:25">` in table it does not work. Why?

[image]

```
@{
ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<h2>Index</h2>
<link href="~/assets/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="dist/bootstrap-clockpicker.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/css/github.min.css">

<script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="dist/bootstrap-clockpicker.min.js"></script> @*it's not a function*@
<script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/highlight.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/knockout-2.2.0.js"></script>

<div class="input-group clockpicker" data-align="top" data-autoclose="true">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" value="13:14">
</div>

<table>
<thead>
    <tr><th>Name</th><th>time</th><th>Time input</th></tr>
</thead>
<tbody data-bind="foreach: items">
    <tr>
        <td data-bind="text: name"></td>
        <td data-bind="text: time"></td>
        <td>
            <div class="input-group clockpicker" data-align="top" data-autoclose="true">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" value="13:25">
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
</table>

<script type="text/javascript">
$('.clockpicker').clockpicker();

function MyViewModel() {
    var self = this;
    self.items = ko.observableArray([{ name: 'jhon', time: '11:00' }, { name: 'David', time: '12:00' }]);
}
ko.applyBindings(new MyViewModel());
</script>
```

Update:

Callendar expanding

```
<ul>
<li>
    <div class="input-group clockpicker" data-align="top" data-autoclose="true">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" value="13:14">
    </div>
</li>
```

Callendar do not expanding

```
<ul data-bind="foreach: items">
<li>
    <div class="input-group clockpicker" data-align="top" data-autoclose="true">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" value="13:14">
    </div>
</li>
```

Problem in knockout?

Comment: maybe data-bind is already reserved? And console show any errors?

Comment: I do not see any errors in console. data-bind using only one time.

Comment: and you tried to put the functional div into clear table if its working?

Comment: In clear table it working well. maybe problem with knockout?

Comment: I guess the problem might be in clock init. KJS create table but clock init is called before than table is done by KJS. Try wrap clock init to timeout fnc and see what happen.

Comment: You are right! Maybe there is some ways to avoid timeout function? Or using timeout function it's normal in such cases. Write answer with timeout and i will accept it because it's working!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is is not working in table because Knockout JS is binding (create) table in other time than clock init is called. You can use setup delay for initalization like:

```
setTimeout(function() {
  $('.clockpicker').clockpicker();
}, 300);
```

It is normal approach but Knockout JS offers own solutions.
One of these useful solutions can be [observable](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/rateLimit-observable.html).